# Reset NSTimer after navigating to another view

Tags: iphone, nstimer, reset

Currently I am developing a game which needs a stop watch say 1 minute,when user taps the play button it enters the game screen,I want the to run the stop watch count down of 1 minute 01:00,00:59,00:58 etc. For that reason I searched and found NSTimer would be the ideal choice to implement a stop watch.Hence I took a label,created an instance of NSTimer,assigned time interval and started decrementing the value in timer label,i.e.:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(viewWillAppear:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    static int currentTime = 60;
    int newTime = currentTime--;
    int minutesRemaining = newTime / 60; // integer division, truncates fractional part
    int secondsRemaining = newTime % 60; // modulo division

    self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutesRemaining, secondsRemaining];

    if ([self.timerLabel.text isEqualToString:@"00:00"])
    {
        [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

The problem here is the timer starts running 01:00,00:59,00:58 and goes on,say at 53rd second,I navigated to another view and came back,it is running from 00:53,00:52 and so on,but I want it to run from 01:00 and for that I implemented invalidating NSTimer in viewDidDisappear i.e.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([stopWatchTimer isValid])
    {
        [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
        self.stopWatchTimer = nil;
    }
    [super viewDidDisappear:YES];
}
```

Still the same issue exists!

Done lots of Research on the issue and found no answer useful and working.

Can some one please guide me,any help is appreciated.

Thanks every one in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are use the selector `viewWillAppear` for the timer. `viewWillAppear` is a method on a viewController that gets called when the view appears on screen, you should not call it yourself. Instead, create your own method that decrements the timer:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  self.stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  currentTime = 60; // This could be an instance variable
  self.timerLabel.text = @"01:00";
}


-(void)updateTime {
  int newTime = currentTime--;
  int minutesRemaining = newTime / 60; // integer division, truncates fractional part
  int secondsRemaining = newTime % 60; // modulo division

  self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutesRemaining, secondsRemaining];

  if ([self.timerLabel.text isEqualToString:@"00:00"])
  {
      [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];
  }
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
  if ([self.stopWatchTimer isValid])
  {
    [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    self.stopWatchTimer = nil;
  }
}
```

With this technique the timer is responsible for calling every second, but you will probably have timing issues after some seconds. To have a more accurate timing, you should store the time that you started the countdown and then on every `updateTime` call, compare the current time with the stored started time.

Add to your interface:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval startTime;
```

then in the implementation:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    self.duration = 60; // How long the countdown should be
    self.stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
    self.timerLabel.text = @"01:00"; // Make sure this represents the countdown time
}

-(void)updateTime {

  int newTime = self.duration - (round([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - self.startTime));
  int minutesRemaining = newTime / 60; // integer division, truncates fractional part
  int secondsRemaining = newTime % 60; // modulo division

  self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutesRemaining, secondsRemaining];

  if (newTime < 1)
  {
    [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];

    /* Do more stuff here */

  }
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
  if ([self.stopWatchTimer isValid])
  {
    [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    self.stopWatchTimer = nil;
  }
}
```

Some extra (unrelated) comments on the code:

when implementing `viewDidDisappear:` pass the `animated` parameter to the call to super:
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
when implementing `viewDidAppear:` pass the `animated` parameter to the call to super, also, make sure you call super first this in the method, before doing anything else

Comment: Perfect Marcel,it worked,but the only problem is the label is displaying previous time say 00:51,then changing to 01:00 and timer works fine,but I don't want that previous time to be visible when I get back to the view.Thanks :)

Comment: I've updated the example code. Make sure you set the text on the label as soon as the view appears.

Comment: It worked Marcel,but there is a slight modification to your answer which would make it work without any issues,I am planning to edit your answer,can I?

Comment: Sorry if I am taking liberty in seeking further help from you,I need help me on another issue,I have a txt file with data,say in the form of @"Cat@milk,Bird@seeds,Man@food" etc. I have extracted the complete data successfully using: NSString *gmatFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"gmatwords" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
self.gmatWordsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[gmatFileString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet nonBaseCharacterSet]]];

Comment: I want 2 different arrays,one array holding cat,bird,man and other holding milk,seeds,food,i.e. the words before @ and after @ symbol

Comment: Maybe you should submit another question?

Comment: Marcel,I am facing a problem with timer,when user selects easy mode,timer runs for 1 minute,if it is medium 2,hard 3,what's happening is the timer is running slow,I mean seconds reducing very slow say taking about 2 seconds time for 1 second time,here is my implementation code: http://pastebin.com/2LGhB8Cw

Comment: Please help me out,kindly read the above comment,the timer is running too slow for 2 and 3 minutes stop watch

Comment: You should store the current time when starting the timer, then make the timerinterval a lot faster. With every `updateTime` call, you compare the current time with the stored time and calculate the seconds difference.

Comment: Can you kindly go through my implementation code and point me where I am wrong.If possible with a few lines of code by editing your answer,here is the link: http://pastebin.com/2LGhB8Cw

Comment: What is dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 and start date,actually we need to specify the time interval when using the method

Comment: Perfect Marcel,it worked,thank you so much for your kind patience :)